# Making a "join" of two collections

Tags: join, collections, meteor

I was wondering if this approach using "observe" still is the recommended approach to achieve joins between two collections.

[Meteor and DBRefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244286/meteor-and-dbrefs#answers-header)

Thanks,
Vindberg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the first meteor meetup I asked one of the core developers this very question. The answer was, unfortunately, yes. Using `observe` is currently the only way to achieve a join, however I was told a solution to this will be added prior to 1.0. I wish I had more information than that. Personally I think the lack of built-in joins is one of meteor's biggest missing features, but I don't see people making a lot of noise about it.

Comment: Yes, I also believe this is a major feature missing. Ken told me of a wrapper on observeChanges:  https://github.com/erundook/meteor-publish-with-relations. I guess that will due until its fully supported.