# Are DBRefs supported in Meteor yet?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, dbref

I am on latest version of Meteor (0.5.9), when I try to insert a document like such:

```
Contacts.insert({ 
     _id : 'gBTqByxvoz9PdFxmy',
     name : 'Albert Einstein',
     infoDocument: {
        '$ref': 'documents',
        '$id': 'zigeoa8RgAukxwYoi',
        '$db': 'meteor'
     },
     owner : 'public',
     slug : 'gBTqByxvoz9PdFxmy',
     type : 'contact' 
}
```

I get an error in the server console "[Error: key $ref must not start with '$']". Are DBRefs supported in Meteor yet?

Comment: Maybe this post can be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244286/meteor-and-dbrefs#answers-header

Comment: Yeah thanks, I've looked at that post and it's direction I'll probably take if DBRefs still aren't supported

Comment: I assume you've already switched to 0.8.2, right? :)

Comment: You might want to check out similar question in Stackoverflow relating to meteor and DBREFs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244286/meteor-and-dbrefs